# creating an array with random binary values (0,1) in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to solve an optimization problem. How can I create an array with 20 random binary values of `[0, 1]`? For instance something like:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, ...]
```

The distribution of these binary values in the array should be random.
Thanks

Comment: Show us what you tried..

Comment: How is this related to genetic algorithms?

Comment: ^ I'm with @jrook: This has nothing to do with genetic algorithms!

Comment: I'm trying to solve an optimization problem related to roads management. So 1: means treat the road ; 0: Don't treat the road . I'm using this array to create an initial random population based on the number of road segments i have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for loop

```js
var arr = [];
for (var i=0;i<20;i++){
     arr.push(Math.round(Math.random()))
}
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array using the constructor, which allows you to set the size, then `Array#fill` it with a value, then `Array#map` it with either 1 or 0 based on `Math.random()`

```js
console.log(
  new Array(20).fill(1).map(x => (Math.random() >= .5) ? 1 : 0)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

Comment: you could return `+(Math.random() >= .5)`, with a casting to number